# Can I obtain coordinates with google places autocomplete?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

I can't understand if I can obtain coordinates with a google places autocomplete response. Or do I have to make an explicit request to google maps with formatted address coming from the google places response?

Answer (score 2):

I'm making two calls one to get the coordinates and fetch the place details using that.
I hope there is no way to do that alone.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the response object: `Result.geometry.location`.

Here is a detailed explanation on the the places response object: 
[Place Details Responses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses)

Answer (score 2):

you can retrive predictions programaticly using AutocompleteService Class with the getPlacePredictions() method [1] to retrive place_id [2]. then with this place_id you can use the Places Details Service [3] to get coordinates and more details of the place.

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

[2]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletePrediction

[3] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

Answer (score 0):

Google for some reason under "optimizations" recommends using their geocode service instead of [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text). I'll have to answer the rest of the stackoverflow questions related to this.

```js
const GOOGLE_MAPS_BASE = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api';
const GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials';

// example code, remember to add error handling for your code
async function searchAndGetCoordExample() {
    const results = await placeSearch('Fiera Capital Toronto');
    const coordinates = [results[0].geometry.location.lat, results[0].geometry.location.lng];
}

export async function placeSearch({ query, language = 'en', limit = 10, lat, lon } = {}) {
    /*
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text
    */
    const locationParam = (lat !== undefined && lon !== undefined) ? `&location=${lat},${lon}` : '';

    const params = new URLSearchParams({
        query,
        language,
        key: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    });

    return await fetchTimeout(`${GOOGLE_MAPS_BASE}/place/textsearch/json?input=${params.toString()}${locationParam}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`).then(r => r.json());
}

async function fetchTimeout(resource, options = {}) {
    // set timeout to 8 seconds from 300 seconds
    // throws Timeout error (error.name === 'AbortError')
    const { timeout = 8000 } = options;
    options.headers = { 'User-Agent': 'MyApp', ...options.headers }
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const id = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout);
    const response = await fetch(resource, {
        ...options,
        signal: controller.signal
    });
    clearTimeout(id);
    return response;
}
```